# how can I hide some tabs on react native tab view?

Tags: react-native, react-native-tab-view

I used tab view react native on my app and I want to hide some tabs by changing settings but I don't know how can I do that.
For now, I have 3 tabs: personal, company and material, in settings I can check the tabs, for example when company is not checked should not appears on tab view

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        { key: 'personal', title: 'personal' },
        { key: 'company', title: 'company' },
        { key: 'material', title: 'material' }
      ],
    };
  }
_renderTabBar = props => {
    return (
      <View>
        <TabBar
          {...props}
          indicatorStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
          renderIcon={
            props => this._getTabBarIcon(props)
          }
          onTabPress={ tab => this.changeTabs(tab)}
          style={{backgroundColor: "#5243af"}}
          tabStyle={styles.tabStyle}
          labelStyle={{fontSize: Fonts.moderateScale(15), marginBottom: 10}}
          contentContainerStyle={{height: Metrics.HEIGHT * 0.1, elevation: 0}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
<TabView style={{ backgroundColor: 'white'}}
                navigationState={this.state}
                renderTabBar={ this._renderTabBar}
                onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
                initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}
                renderScene={this._renderScene} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make custom own tabbar and manage the tab visibility according to condition , for more understanding follow this link

[Hide TabBar item in TabNavigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954189/hide-tabbar-item-in-tabnavigator)

it will help you

Comment: thakns for the reply, for me I used [https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view] I'm working on mobile app, but if I can understand you , may create a my own tabbar component

Comment: is there any other solutions?

Comment: there is no more easy solution as compare this.

Comment: thank you I have created my own custom tabbar and now works well

Answer (score -1):

```
tabBar hidden =>
    <TabView 
        renderToTabbar={ ()=> <></> }
    />
```